# Fetching data with React useState getting wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm having a problem with this code, can you help me out please?
I've created an id state to get an id from an API because I need this ID to make another FETCH

```
const [id, setId] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      await fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations', requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result =>
          setId(...id, result)
        )
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])
```

So here I have an array of IDs that I will use in the next fetch...

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        id.map(companyId => {
            async function fetchData() {
                await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations/${companyId.id}/licenses`, requestOptions)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(result =>
                        setData([...data, { company: companyId.name, results: result}]))
                    .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
            }
            setIsLoading(false)
            fetchData()
        })
    }, [id])
```

The problem here is... I'm getting a NEW "data" for every id, so it's changing every fetch, and I know its because I used [id] at the end of my useState, but I need to get FOR EACH id, a new "data", how is that possible?

When I try to render it with an Empty array on the end of useState, it returns me only an empty array, since its just rendering one time. How can I get for each ID that I got in "id" array on the first fetch, a data containing all the results from the second fetch?

PS: requestOptions are hidden because of the API Key....

Comment: How are those two hooks connected? Can you pls give a bit more context?

Comment: The first useEffect is an API request to get an array that gives me the ID of each company, because I will need this ID for the second fetch "/${companyId.id}/licenses". Lets say that both hooks are on the same script (App.js), after getting this "[id]" on the first hook, I need to use it for the second hook, to get all data for each id(company). The problem I'm having is that everytime I "setData()" on the second hook, it just erase the past data that I fetched and gives me a new one (Because I'm using [id] at the end of the useEffect. I would like to store all DATA for each ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add one more element to the previous state, you can pass a function to `setData()` that allows you to update the old state instead of replacing it.
In your example i would change the `setData` call by returning a new array that contains the old state plus the new element. It's important to use the spread operator instead of .push() method so that state does not get mutated directly.
`setData(prevState => [...prevState, { company: companyId.name, results: result}])`